# android set adapter to linear layout

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to put a list view in a scroll view which is not possible as I found in several similar questions.

I have a quite large menu to be placed above list view, which completely hides the list view on small screens, so I need a scroll view which is not possible. I read that I should use a linear layout instead of list view to solve this problem. But not sure how to setup up an adapter on linearlayout. I am using a lazy adapter for image loading in the list view.

Code:

```
LinearLayout list=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listActivities);
adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, activityList);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question there is a single view that you wonna put at the top of your list view. Try to use `ListView.addHeaderView(View v)` for that purpose. See [android API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) for more info.

Comment: But how would I be able to get the View? my view is in menu.xml

Comment: ok i found it, LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.myfile, null);

Answer (score 1):

You can add a view as header to the list view, which will solve your problem, it will place the view in the list view but on the top of list items.

`listview.addHeaderView(yourview)`

Answer (score 1):

you can add HorizontalScrollView in your listview header where in HorizontalScrollView you can add linearlayout & horizontal menus in it

or

other option is to have one simple button in header of listview say action & clicking on that open new dialog with list of menus (actions) etc...